# Using filters on image gallery through links

Tags: php, html, filter, nav

First of all, my english is not the best so i'll try my best to explain what i'm trying to do:

I have an image gallery in my website where all of the images are stored in a database. Each image has a type of category and there is a table on the database with all of the categories.

Underneath the image gallery i have this nav with all the categories listed:

```
<nav class="cl-effect-5">
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="All">All</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="Black and White">Black and white</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="Panoramic">Panoramic</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="Nature">Nature</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="City">City</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="Others">Others</span></a>
                </nav>
```

I want the user to click one of these categories and the gallery will only show pictures that have that category but i don't know how to do it and i'm not very skillfull in coding.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

in JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cl-effect-5 a span ').click(function() {
  var selected=$(this).attr('data-hover');
  $.get("query.php?selected="+selected, function(data){
  $('.result').html(data);

   });
 });
});
```

and you should create query.php file and your query and code in it and return the result in it

```
 $type = $_POST["selected"];

 $query="select * from table where type='".$type."'";
 $html="";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $html .= $row['image_link'];
  }
 echo $html ;
```